# Converting a string into the correct format for DataObject.GetText()

Tags: vba

I’m trying to loop through a string array for the argument of DataObject.GetText(), but I keep getting

> Runtime Error ‘13’ : Type Mismatch

Here are the relevant pieces that I have so far:

```
Dim L as Integer, OldL as String
Dim Loc(1 to 19) as String
Loc(1) = “0, 5, 14”: Loc(2) = “31, 5, 7”: ...
.
.
.
For L = 1 to 19
    OldL = Trim([Object].GetText(Loc(L))) ‘This is where the problem is
.
.
.
Next L
```

Thank you.

Comment: where are you adding data to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of an idea that works, but I'm still open to suggestions if anyone has them.

Here are my changes:

```
Dim L As Integer, OldL As String
Dim a(1 to 19) As Integer, b(1 to 19) As Integer, c(1 to 19) As Integer
.
.
.
For L = 1 to 19
    OldL = Trim([Object].GetText(a(L), b(L), c(L)))
.
.
.
Next L
```